Why hasn't SpaceX performed a Wet Dress Rehearsal of Starship if they are ready to fly?
SpaceX claims that "The Starship and Super Heavy vehicles for Flight 5 have been ready to launch since the first week of August." SpaceX usually performs Wet Dress Rehearsals (WDRs) before launching its rockets, even with the Falcon 9, and always does before launching Starship. It seems very likely that SpaceX will not launch Starship without performing a WDR.
So, why don't they perform a WDR with Starship if they are ready to fly? Wouldn't it make sense to do "check off" everything they can from their list of things necessary before launching, if they have been just waiting for 2 months?
Additionally, they have nearly 2 more months until the FAA NET (No Earlier Than) date for a launch license. If something does in fact go wrong during the WDR, doing one now would give them nearly 2 months to fix it without actually delaying the launch at all. Why wouldn't they do this?

real mechanical systems aren't inert; running a WDR and then waiting two months doesn't mean the WDR results are still valid.

So perhaps you could run another one. But don't you think there is at least the benefit of "we might catch something 2 months earlier and give ourselves 2 months of time to fix it without delaying us" @ErinAnne

coincidentally(?) NSF Live shows tanking today, though NSF called it a "partial WDR":  https://youtu.be/Xv2lzAPsTlw?t=4075.  The NSF answer that "you verify whatever you want to verify" is probably all we get without an official announcement about what they're doing.

On September 23 and then again on October 7, SpaceX performed partial Wet Dress Rehearsals of Starship. Given that they launched Flight 5 on October 13, and did not perform any other WDR, those were likely the only tests they intended to do.
So, essentially, Starship had already done as much of a WDR as it was going to.
